# Is there a function and a point such that $|f(x)|$ is differentiable at that point but $f(x)$ is not?

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

Is there a function $f(x)$ and a point $x=a$ such that $|f(x)|$ differentiable at $x=a$ but $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=a$?

Isn’t it the absolute value that is creating sharp points which makes the function not differentiable? (e.g. $|x|$ at $x=0$).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Consider$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^x&x\ge0\\-e^x&x\lt0\end{cases}$$at the point $x=0$. Note that $|f(x)|=e^x$ is differentiable everywhere but $f(x)$ is not even continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you allow $f$ to be discontinuous, then you can potentially use $\vert\cdot\vert$ to remove discontinuities. Consider for example the function
$$f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, x \mapsto \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & x\geq 0\\ -1 & x<0\end{array}\right.$$
It clearly is not continuous in 0 but $\vert f \vert$ is a constant function, hence differentiable.

$\vert \cdot \vert$ creating sharp points is only possible, if it is applied to a function, whose output switches signs. Even then it doesn’t have to kill differentiability. For example I think the function
$$g:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, x \mapsto \vert x^3\vert$$
is differentiable, with
$$g‘:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, x \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
3x^2 &x>0\\
0 & x=0\\
-3x^2 & x <0
\end{array}\right.$$